# backbonejs jquery mobile view rendering screwed up if we render inside websql transaction

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, backbone-views

Folks,
Consider the view below in coffeescript:

```
window.Aview = class AView extends Backbone.View

  getT: (callback) =>
    callback()

  getTransactions: (callback) =>
    @getT( =>
      callback()
    )            
  render: =>
   @getTransactions(
     (results) =>
       $(@el).html(@template({}))
   )
```

This renders as expected (shown below):
[image: correct rendering of tabs]

However, if I change the logic in getTransactions to use window.db.transaction (window.db points to a websql db variable), as follows:

```
  getTransactions: (callback) =>
    window.db.transaction( =>
      callback()
    )
```

then the rendering gets screwed up as shown below:

[image: incorrect rendering when we use window.db.transaction]

I am not sure why this happens. I think this is most likely not the way to use backbonejs but I am curious why the rendering of jquery mobile tab gets messed up when I use window.db.transaction instead of the locally defined getT method.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I was doing it wrong at multiple levels as I suspected. The goal here was to render data that you from websql database. The problem is that the database data gets returned via a callback asynchronously. Your view somehow needs to "wait" till the data is done. The correct way is

1. Use jquery deferreds (see http://eng.wealthfront.com/2012/12/jquerydeferred-is-most-important-client.html article)
2. In the render method of backbonejs view - render the page without the data using regular backbone js render mechanism
3. Render the dynamic content (the data your query returns asynchonously) using the jquery promise interface:
   txnsLoadedPromise.then(
   // render dynamic stuff here
   )
4. Call trigger create to apply jquery enhancements (see http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/faq/injected-content-is-not-enhanced.php
   )
   The reason I was getting screwed up UI was because the jquery enhancements need to be applied programmatically for dynamic DOM elements.